# Tcl open file then read, added wired chars not exist in original file

Tags: linux, unicode, character-encoding, tcl

I am doing so :

```html
set fileIdSource [open 20801.iim "r"]
set file_data [read $fileIdSource]
puts "=========\n$file_data\n========="
close $fileIdSource
```

the file 20801.iim is :
[image]

then I run it in tcl I get 2 wired chars before "VERSION"  :

[image]

Y is it happends ? TNX.

Comment: Looks like the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte order mark) to me.

Answer (score 0):

Those two characters are (probably) the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM). The encoding that the file was written in was probably UTF-8 with some level of encoding of it, and it's being slightly misinterpreted. Tcl doesn't process the BOM (except for Tcl scripts) as there are cases where the programmer does have to care. They *should* be a single character that is written at the beginning of the file (it gets written as a multi-byte sequence) and should be read as a single character by Tcl, but for some reason that isn't happening here. (What is the value returned by `encoding system` on your test platform?)

You can ignore them, even strip them (they should only ever occur) as long as you put the BOM back when you write the string out. Writing the BOM is just a matter of doing:

```
puts -nonewline $theChannel "\ufeff"
```

before writing anything else to that file (provided you're using one of the Unicode-based encodings). But it's usually entirely unnecessary to do so unless you're writing either a full multibyte encoding *or* writing UTF-8 on Windows (because reasons).